# Multidimensional explanatory variable in decision tree

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree

Is it possible (by any available package) to build a decision tree based model with multidimensional response (/e dependent) variable in R?
Let's assume we have random variable `Y = [Y1, Y2, Y3]` and corresponding data frame of observation of `Y` - `df.Y` (`dim(df.Y) = 3 x rows`). Variables `Y1`, `Y2` and `Y3` depends on each other and because of that I'm not able to do 3 decision trees for each Y1, Y2, Y3 separately.

I'm looking something similar to `rpart` or `randomForest` but I'm interested in model's formula like

```
`df.Y ~ X1 + X2`
```

where variables `X1, X2` are one-dimensional.

Thanks in advance for any pice of information :)

UPDATE:
I forgot to mention that variables `Y1, Y2` and `Y3` are continuous and dependent. In discrete case it is easy to "merge" levels of response variables.

Comment: This post may be of interest to you http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41697/prediction-results-for-two-response-variable-from-random-forest

Comment: By "explanatory variable" do you mean "response variable"? Explanatory variables are usually the x-variables, the independent variables, that are used to *explain* the variation in response or dependent variables.

Comment: Aw, my bad. Yes I meant response (dependent) variable.

Comment: Yes. It is possible.

Comment: @Alex could you tell me how it is possible in R? I am aware of doing it by define a measure on multidimensional space and basically rewrite decision tree algorithm on my own, but in this case I don't have enough time for that.